# Polynomial identity : $|P(z)|^2=|Q(z)|^2-|R(z)|^2$ for $z \in \mathbb{D}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-geometry, analytic-functions, maximum-principle

Let us denote by $\mathbb{D}=\{z : |z| <1\}$ and $\mathbb{T}=\{z: |z|=1\}$. Suppose that $P, Q$ and $R$ are polynomials that satisfy the following:

1. $|Q(z)| \geq |R(z)| $ for all $z \in \overline{\mathbb{D}}$
2. $|P(z)|^2=|Q(z)|^2-|R(z)|^2$ for $z \in \mathbb{T}$
3. $P$ and $Q$ are non-vanishing on $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$
4. $|P(z)|^2 \leq |Q(z)|^2-|R(z)|^2$ for $z \in \mathbb{D}$.

My question : $|P(z)|^2=|Q(z)|^2-|R(z)|^2$ for $z \in \mathbb{D}$?

I am trying to prove it. I think some version of maximum-modulus or identity theorem can be useful here. But what functions to choose to apply maximum modulus. Any hint how to proceed.

My Attempt: Note that for any $z \in \mathbb{T}$, we have $P(z)\overline{P(\frac{1}{\overline{z}})}=|P(z)|^2$. Thus, condition (2) implies that $P(z)\overline{P(\frac{1}{\overline{z}})}= Q(z)\overline{Q(\frac{1}{\overline{z}})} -R(z)\overline{R(\frac{1}{\overline{z}})} $ for all $z \in \mathbb{T}$. Hence, the map

$F: \mathbb{D}\setminus \{0\} \to \mathbb{C}, F(z)= P(z)\overline{P(\frac{1}{\overline{z}})} - Q(z)\overline{Q(\frac{1}{\overline{z}})} - R(z)\overline{R(\frac{1}{\overline{z}})}$ is zero on $\mathbb{T}$.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't true in general.

First, thanks to Conrad for pointing out a problem with my earlier answer that claimed to prove this. As he noted, if we let $Q$ be an arbitrary polynomial that doesn't vanish on the closed disk, and pick constants $a,b$ such that $|a|^2 + |b|^2 = 1$, then $P = aQ$ and $R = bQ$ satisfy the hypotheses and conclusion. This gives some examples of polynomials for which this works.

Suppose $P, Q, R$ are polynomials that satisfy the hypotheses and conclusion. Then $P, Q, z^n R$ also satisfy the hypotheses if $n$ is a positive integer:

1. $|Q(z)| \geq |R(z)| \geq |z^n R(z)|$  for all $z \in \overline{\mathbb{D}}$ as $|z^n| \leq 1$ there.
2. $|P(z)|^2 = |Q(z)|^2 - |R(z)|^2 = |Q(z)|^2 - |z^n R(z)|^2$ when $|z| = 1$.
3. $P$ and $Q$ do not vanish on the closed disk.
4. $|P(z)|^2 \leq |Q(z)|^2 - |R(z)|^2 < |Q(z)|^2 - |z^n R(z)|^2$ on $\mathbb{D}$.

However, as the strict inequality in the last point shows, the conclusion does not hold.

If the conclusion holds, then we can consider $f = P/Q$ and $g = R/Q$ on the closed disk. The equation
$$
\partial \bar\partial \log(|f|^2 + |g|^2)
= \frac{|fg' - f'g|^2}{(|f|^2 + |g|^2)^2}
$$
and that $|f|^2 + |g|^2 = 1$ on the disk imply that $f'/f = g'/g$, so $g = a f$ for some constant $a$. Then $|f|^2$ is constant on the disk, so $P = bQ$ for some constant $b$, and we are in the situation Conrad described.

Comment: Note that one can have $P=aQ, R=bQ$ with $|a|^2+|b|^2=1$ and $Q$ arbitrary non vanishing on the unit disc

Comment: @Conrad So one can!

Comment: This means that something is not quite right in the argument above if I am not mistaken

Comment: @Conrad Well, yes, clearly.

Comment: @Conrad I think I figured this out. Thanks for the correction earlier.

Comment: now looks correct - the more interesting question to me is if we have only $2,3$ in the OP can we deduce that $P=aQ$ (and $R=bBQ$ where $B$ is some Blaschke product); in other words if $|f|^2+|g|^2=1$ on the unit circle only, where $f,g$ analytic inside the unit disc and on a neighborhood of it say, and neither $f,g$ vanish inside the unit disc, does it follow $f,g$ constant - the nonvanishing is not a big deal as one can take out finitely many zeroes with a Blaschke product that preserves the unit circle relation and $f,g$ cannot have zeroes accumulating to the unit circle